# Django rest framework update method in API view to changing values in db json

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have an api.py view written as follows in a django rest framework project:

```
class StudentAcademicProgramList2(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        student_academic_program = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951)
        serialized_Student_academic_program = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer2(student_academic_program, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_Student_academic_program.data)

    def update(self, request, format=None):
        student_academic_program = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951)
        serializer = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer2(student_academic_program, many=True)

        for x in xrange(0,len(serializer.data)):
            serializer.primary_program = False

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer2(data = request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        student_academic_program = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951)
        student_academic_program.delete()
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The json it gets is of the following format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3684, 
        "student": 2773951, 
        "academic_program": 595, 
        "credits_completed": 28, 
        "academic_program_gpa": null, 
        "primary_program": false
    }, 
    {
        "id": 3685, 
        "student": 2773951, 
        "academic_program": 596, 
        "credits_completed": 26, 
        "academic_program_gpa": null, 
        "primary_program": true
    }
]
```

Both these classes work well whenever i get and post some data in the json api.

How do i write an `update()` function in the apiview so that it changes all the `primary_program` values in the json to false? The update function i wrote will not work because of the for loop. How can i change this function?

Edit:

I tried @Fabiano 's answer but the serializer was nout updating anything in the db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```python
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.DATA
    qs = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951)
    serializer = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(qs, data=data, many=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data)

    ...
```

Or you can allow the user to do a Patch, in this case you just need to add ´partial=True´ on the serializer constructor.
If you allow the user to do a Patch, then the user can change only the primary_program field.

```python
    serializer = StudentAcademicProgramSerializer(qs, data=data, many=True, partial=True)
```

You can see more at the docs:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#dealing-with-multiple-objects

Comment: will this code change the values of all the primary_program values to false? where are we mentioning that statement?

Comment: You can set data = [{'id': your_id, 'primary_program': False}] instead use data as request.DATA

Comment: hi...can you help mere here?? it is the same question with a little more functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066368/django-adding-more-functionality-to-my-views-update-function